# Add Custom TFS Groups to Stakeholder Access Level

Tags: tfs

We are using an on-premises TFS 2013 Update 4 server, and are trying to add people to our Stakeholders list so they can see work items.  The easiest way for us to do this is with groups.  However, when we go to the Access Levels tab, click "Add..." and choose TFS Group, we are only able to choose from a very small list of server level TFS groups.

Is there a way to add a custom project collection level TFS Group to this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The user rights allocation is done at the server level an has no knowledge groups at the collection level.

You should however be able to create a custom server level group and add that.

Comment: Here a note for all those, who wonder how to create server level groups: The TFS Web Access page does not offer such a functionality, but you can find it in the Administration Console (Application/Group Membership), see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd567714%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396